# Using Facebook Graph API Explorer to publish a custom open graph history

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

From Graph API Explorer of Facebook I'm trying to publish a story on my wall, without success.

The post was to URL: /2.4/me/**my_app_name_space**:**my_action**
with a parameter as: **my_object_type** : **id_of_my_object**

The request seems was ok because the response:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "created_time": "2015-08-06T16:09:02+0000",
      "title": "My title",
      "type": "<my_name_space>:<my_object_type>",
      "id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      "count": 8,
      "first_action_id": "XXXXXXXXXX",
      "first_time": "2015-09-10T09:42:07+0000",
      "last_action_id": "XXXXXXX",
      "last_time": "2015-09-11T19:24:38+0000"
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "YYYYYYYYYYYYYY",
      "after": "YYYYYYYYYYYYYY"
    }
  }
}
```

Well, I went immediately to my wall but nothing was published. 
So I make a GET request to path: /2.4/me/**my_app_name_space**:**my_action**/**my_object_type** and the response contains the previous object.

Does it means the POST query was ok? But then, why the story is not published?

Comment: Do you see it in the Activity log?

Comment: yes I see it on my activity log

Comment: Then everything is working

Comment: But it doesnt appear on my wall

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for the explicitly shared parameter.

```
fb:explicitly_shared=true
```

Further info here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/using-actions#explicit